# Amount of specific element in list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am beginner and have a question; is there a faster way to get amount of specific element in list?

```
a = [False, True, False, True, True]
e = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i] == True:
        e.append(a[i])
print(len(e))
```

Comment: Well in this specific case you could just use `sum(a)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Comment: This is a duplicate, had you done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: the `count` method.

```
print(a.count(True))
```